# How to get result from background process linux shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

For example let's say I want to count the number of lines of 10 BIG files and print a total.

```
for f in files
do
    #this creates a background process for each file
    wc -l $f | awk '{print $1}' &
done
```

I was trying something like:

```
for f in files
do
    #this does not work :/
    n=$( expr $(wc -l $f | awk '{print $1}') + $n ) &
done

echo $n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use gnu parallel:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | parallel --gnu 'wc -l' | awk 'BEGIN {n=0} {n += $1} END {print n}'
```

or else xargs in parallel mode:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | xargs -n1 -P4 wc -l | awk 'BEGIN {n=0} {n += $1} END {print n}'
```

Another option, if this doesn't fit your needs, is to write to temp files.  If you don't want to write to disk, just write to /dev/shm.  This is a ramdisk on most Linux systems.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a temp_files

count=0
for f in *
do
  if [[ -f "$f" ]]; then
    temp_files[$count]="$(mktemp /dev/shm/${f}-XXXXXX)"
    ((count++))
  fi
done

count=0
for f in *
do
  if [[ -f "$f" ]]; then
    cat "$f" | wc -l > "${temp_files[$count]}" &
    ((count++))
  fi
done

wait

cat "${temp_files[@]}" | awk 'BEGIN {n=0} {n += $1} END {print n}'

for tf in "${temp_files[@]}"
do
  rm "$tf"
done
```

By the way, this can be though of as a map-reduce with wc doing the mapping and awk doing the reduction.

Comment: find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | xargs -n1 -P4 wc -l | awk 'BEGIN {n=0} {n += $1} END {print n}' works perfect. But I went with the /dev/shm since I like to have a dynamic number of background processes.

Comment: You may want to be a bit careful, if you have a 1000 files you will end up with 1000 processes, this might really bog down your machine.  It takes some extra work to ensure a limit on the number of processes.

Comment: I will, for now I have 10 files that have around 20-30GB size.

Answer (score 3):

I finally found a working solution using anonymous pipes and bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

# this executes a separate shell and opens a new pipe, where the 
# reading endpoint is fd 3 in our shell and the writing endpoint
# stdout of the other process. Note that you don't need the 
# background operator (&) as exec starts a completely independent process.
exec 3< <(./a.sh 2&1)


# ... do other stuff


# write the contents of the pipe to a variable. If the other process
# hasn't already terminated, cat will block.
output=$(cat <&3)
```

Comment: I think this will create a file  named "3". I'm Trying not to write into disk.

Answer (score 0):

You could write that to a file or better, listen to a fifo as soon as data arrives.

Here is a small example on how they work:

```
# create the fifo
mkfifo test

# listen to it
while true; do if read line <test; then echo $line; fi done

# in another shell 
echo 'hi there'

# notice 'hi there' being printed in the first shell
```

So you could

```
for f in files
do
    #this creates a background process for each file
    wc -l $f | awk '{print $1}' > fifo &
done
```

and listen on the fifo for sizes.